# Removing touch event listeners from single objects removes touch functionality from all other objects on the screen

Tags: android, iphone, lua, coronasdk

I want to remove touch listeners from a single object and want to remove listeners from gameloop but the problem is, if i remove touch listeners from ball object, touch event listeners also gets removed from the other objects which includes button also, which i want to press to continue on the next screen, below are the blue print of the codes but it is not exact code what i am using. Please try to solve the problem .. thanks

```
function displayScreen()
    local btnGroup = display.newGroup()
    local graphic = display.newRect( 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight)
    graphic:setFillColor(0, 0, 0, 50)
    btnGroup:insert(graphic)
    ball:removeEventListener("touch", moveball)
    restartMenu()
end

 function restartMenu()
    local menuGp = display.newGroup()
    graphic1 = display.newImageRect("Reset.png", 564, 216,true )
    graphic1.x = display.contentWidth / 2
    graphic1.y = display.contentHeight - display.contentHeight / 4
    graphic1:addEventListener("touch", restart)
    menuGp:insert(graphic1)
end

function restart()
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are using Runtime for your touch events. So it's natural that all other objects touch listeners are removed. If you want to manupulate event listeners individually you should create event listeners just for one object. What I mean is something like that:

```
local ball = display.newCircle( 250, 250, 60 )
ball.x = display.contentCenterX
ball.y = display.contentCenterY
ball:setFillColor(240, 200, 0)
ball:addEventListener( "touch", ballTouchHandler )
```

And for removing;

```
ball:removeEventListener( "touch", ballTouchHanler )
```

I dont suggest to use Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", functiıon() {} ) at all.
You should use it only with "enterFrame" functions

Comment: I have corrected it but the same issue is there i have edited my code, the event from graphics1 object also gets removed which is a type of button. Please suggest any idea of how to sulve it... thanks

Comment: the issue i am facing is that i want to move an object on the screen, for that i have used a function, but if i remove an event while holding that object then from the other objects touch events gets removed.....

Comment: everything seems okay to me, can you share more code blocks ? Because you are creating global objects from a function's scope. Maybe you use them in other places.